# Foreign Key data type

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, primary-key, rdbms

I have two classes in **models.py** in my DJango Project.

```
class person(models.Model):-
    field1 = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    person_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

class orders(models.Model):-
    field22 = models.ForeignKey(person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

As observed in the above two models,**field22** is a foreign key that is mapped to the primary key of the table **person**.

Now, What will be the **datatype** of field22, int (or) str? (or) it will inherit the data type of the primary key?

Comment: Foreign keys have to have the same datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the primary keys of person table, field22 in orders table will contain integers. 
The point is than as it is a foreign key you cannot perform operation as a standard integer.

For exemple:
In table person you have two rows:

field / person

1     / MrX

2     /   MrY

In table orders

pk(automatic) /field22 / otherfield

1            / 2        /text2.1

2            /1       / text1.1

3            /1       / text1.2

If you want to look in table orders for MrX you will have to get an Instance of MrX in person table and search result in orders tables:

```
#get instance
instancePerson=person.objects.get(person="MrX")
#and then look in orders
search=orders.objects.filter(field22=instancePerson).values_list('otherfield' )
print(search) 

#output:
['text1.1','text1.2']
```

If for exemple you try to search by the value of field22:

```
search=orders.objects.filter(field22=1).values_list('otherfield' )
```

You will raise an exception which will explain you than an instance was expected and received 1.
Hope it answered to your question.